# magento: override Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query ends with Invalid Method prepareResult

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I try to override Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query.

Now I tried to do it as minimal as possible:

**adding rewrite block to config.xml**

```
<config>
...
  <global>
    <models>
      ...
      <catalogsearch>
        <rewrite>
          <fulltext>MyCompany_CatalogSearch_Model_Query</fulltext>
        </rewrite>
      </catalogsearch>
    </models>
  </global>
</config>
```

**adding my class**

```
    <?php

    class MyCompany_CatalogSearch_Model_Query extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query
    {
    }
```

**But I get**

> Invalid method MyCompany_CatalogSearch_Model_Query::prepareResult(Array
>   (
>   )
>   )

I don't provide any prepareResult, but when I don't override the Query class, it is working so I should inherit this method, I think?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to do the rewrite of the Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext class, not the Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Query one. And this is triggering the issue.

When calling the catalogsearch/fulltext, one should use the prepareResult method, that is absent in the catalogsearch/query.

If you goal is to rewrite the catalogsearch/query, rewrite the config in this way:

```
  <catalogsearch>
    <rewrite>
      <query>MyCompany_CatalogSearch_Model_Query</query>
    </rewrite>
  </catalogsearch>
```

If you aim at rewriting the Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext class, do it this way:

```
class MyCompany_CatalogSearch_Model_Query extends Mage_CatalogSearch_Model_Fulltext
    {
    }
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works :) Copy & paste is not my friend, when creating config.xmls. Additionally, I find it difficult to know exactly which values are needed in a special way and which ones just have to be unique (but can be made up) in those xml files. That's why I don't pay attention to them that much sometimes.